# Issue with Sum of Floors in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm using Mathematica 8.  When I try the command

```
Sum[r^n Floor[n/2], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

I get

```
r^2/((-1 + r)^2 (1 + r))
```

which is correct, but starting from `1` instead of `0`:

```
Sum[r^n Floor[n/2], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

gives

```
r/((-1 + r)^2 (1 + r))
```

which is not.  What's going on?

Comment: wow! looks like a bug to me. adding a zero to the sum should not make a difference.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, you should post that as an answer, as it is correct. I'd drop the sarcasm, though.

Comment: Similar problem when `Floor` is replaced with `Ceiling`.

Comment: Another problem: when `IntegerPart[n/2]` is used instead of `Floor[n/2]` both sums are incorrect:`Sum[(r^n ) IntegerPart[n/2], {n, 0, Infinity}]` gives `(2*r^2)/((-1 + r)^2*(1 + r))` and `Sum[(r^n ) IntegerPart[n/2], {n, 0, Infinity}]` gives `r/((-1 + r)^2*(1 + r))`.

Comment: @Verbeia Having merely a tag seems to work quite well, though.

Comment: @AndrewMacFie No, not really. We have problems with people not understanding Mathematica is a language as well as an IDE and more. Many questions were downvoted or closed because people thought they were related to mathematics and hence were off-topic. With a dedicated site we can broaden the scope considerably.

Comment: Case in point: the question after yours just got closed for this reason (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8692674/615464). Hope it get reopened soon.

Comment: @AndrewMacFie also many questions (eg about configuration, stylesheets, etc) would be off topic here on StackOverflow. We want to consolidate questions about Mathematica in one place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug. Please submit bug report to WRI (email: support@wolfram.com)

Comment: Should I submit it here: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback?  I submitted some bugs there before but they didn't get fixed.

Comment: @AndrewMacFie the email address is support@wolfram.com. Bugs may take one or more versions to get removed, so don't expect an immediate fix.